# How can I update an instance variable with the value of a function variable?

Tags: java, android, global-variables

I just started programming in android studio in the last few months and i have been wondering , can i update the value of an instance variable with the value of a variable that is in a function? To make this more clear

**JAVA CODE**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
              double latitudine, longitudine;
              Location currentLocation;
              Location newLocation;


Task location1 = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
              location1.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                 currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();


Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,""+currentLocation.getLatitude(),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,""+currentLocation.getLongitude(),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   newLocation = currentLocation ;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"no way",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I simply want to use the value stored in currentLocation in some other places in my project , but how can i do that ?

Comment: It depends on where do you want to use it, in another activity, fragment, or just a nonactivity class, how many times you want to use it and ...

Comment: i just need to use the value of currentLocation it in other function

Comment: Currentlocation is an object in which you define it as a property, so you can use it all through your class